# How do i get the min and max value of tuples

Tags: python

How do i get the code to return 2 (lowest of all) and 29 (the biggest one)

```
intervals = [
    (2, 18),
    (2, 15),
    (5, 28),
    (10, 14),
    (11, 29),
    (6, 17),
    (3, 7),
    (8, 22)
]

z = max(intervals)
print (z)
```

Comment: You could flatten the data and then take the max and min.

Comment: Do you want the lowest and highest among all values, the lowest from the left and the highest from the right, or what? What's the expected solution for  `[(10,2)]` and `[(1,100), (20,50)]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When searching for the `min`, you want to first take the `min` of each `tuple` and then take the `min` through those. You can achieve this with `map` which has the advantage of not having to create an extra list in the process.

```
z_max = max(map(max, intervals))
z_min = min(map(min, intervals))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
low = min(intervals, key=lambda x:x[0])[0]
high = max(intervals, key=lambda x:x[1])[1]
```

in single pass

```
 val =sorted(intervals, key=lambda x:(x[0], x[1]))
 low, high = val[0][0], val[-1][1]
```

Comment: @sahasrara62 Fun fact: you could replace you key parameters by min and max respectively here.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it like this:

```
intervals = [
    (2, 18),
    (2, 15),
    (5, 28),
    (10, 14),
    (11, 29),
    (6, 17),
    (3, 7),
    (8, 22)
]

items = [item for interval in intervals for item in interval]
print(max(items))
print(min(items))
```